# Express.js - req.query vs req.params

Tags: node.js, http, express, url-routing, express-router

*Before you mark this as a duplicate, please understand that I was not able to get the explanations I was looking for from other answers.*

If I was making an app that looked for a customer based on a URL id, what is the difference between saying `customers/1234` and using `req.params` and `customers?id=1234` and using `req.query`? What do the two url data methods do differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no difference whatsoever from the performance or functionality. is about the standards specifically restful vs non restful urls. usually on restful services the resources identification portion lies on the path and the query or search is used for filtering purposes. this is considered a good practice and it is convention. there is no actual technical reason behind it other than being easier to read and identify. you can learn more about this in places like

https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Among others.
It is all about what you are trying to build and how close to the standards do you want to stay

Answer (score 1):

According to the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/th/api.html#req) it looks like the differences between `req.query` and `req.params` are just as you mentioned, in that they are a different way to achieve a similar end result. Which you choose is really just a matter of your personal preference for how you want to pass data to Express.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, but `customers/1234` is prettier than `customers?id=1234` in URLs.

**It depends on what you prefer**, but if you compare websites, you'll see that many of them use the first syntax. Look at Stackoverflow for example.